# how to get element value where multiple class name is same in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a page that retrieves data from database and displays it in tabular format in brief. There is a hyperlink and clicking on it displays the details of a record.

here is some code

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
   result = result + "<tr><td><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='detailStud' iditem='"
     + response.studs[i].regd+"'>Details</a></td></tr>";
}
```

on JQuery side

```
$('.detailStud').click(function(){

var val1= $(this).attr('iditem');

alert(val1);});
```

But this is not working....
please help ....

Comment: is it returning undefined in alert or alert is not thrown

Comment: [Use `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), and retrieve them with `$(this).data('iditem')`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That you are able to get the element value of only one of the element but you want the values of all the elements with the same class name? Or are you getting no values at all? Or are getting some error with the above code?

Comment: *"this is not working"* is not  proper problem statement. If event delegation doesn't solve problem then update question with proper explanation and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Mr Ben  $('#listStudDiv').on("click","a.detailStud",function(){
         alert($(this).attr('iditem'));
        });